# Nginx subdirectory try_files wildcard always fail

Tags: nginx, wildcard

Nginx 1.10.3 Ubuntu, standard apt installation. `index index.php;` located outside `server` block.

I need:

- `http://example.com/test/1` pointing to
  `/var/www/example.com/test/1`
- `http://example.com/test/2` pointing to
  `/var/www/example.com/test/2`

..and so on.

Because I will create too many test, I need a wildcard for `try_files`. Currently I'm doing without wildcard:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    location /test/1/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/1/index.php?$args;
    }
    location /test/2/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/2/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}
```

Out of many recommendations, none of them works.

Plain PHP running fine. WordPress & Laravel gave "File not found":

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location ~ ^/test/(?<content>.+)$ {
        root   /var/www/example.com/test/$content;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}
```

File not found:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location ~ ^/test/(?<content>[^/]+) {
        root   /var/www/example.com/test/$content;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}
```

On all attempts below, It download the PHP file instead of run PHP:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    location ~ /(?<content>[^/]+) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$content/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    location ~ /(.*)/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    location ~ /test/(?<content>[^/]+) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/$content/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    location ~ /test/(?<content>.+) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/$content/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
}
```

If can, I willing to give $10 for the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order, so the `.php` block must be placed before the `/test/...` block, otherwise the `.php` files under `/test/` will be downloaded instead of being executed. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Your best version was second from last. The regular expression extracts just the path element following the `/test/` prefix.

Just reverse the `location` blocks. For example:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
    location ~ /test/(?<content>[^/]+) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/$content/index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I use `index.php?$query_string` for Laravel. I still figure out how I can reward you.